#  replace while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) loop with for loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I was wondering how I could replace this loop:
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
by an for loop.

I want to know, because on my website, I want to show the data on my website, but the first row needs a different layout as the rest.

So what I would like to have, is something like this:

```
$row[0]

for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
$row[$i]
}
```

I tried a bit of searching here, but couldnt find something that seemed logical to me: most examples I saw would execute a new sql query to the server, which isnt very good for the speed, is it?

Please let me know!

Comment: You don't need to use `for` to have a counter

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did someone downvote this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do it that way.  I would do something like this:

```
$first=true;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    if ($first) {
        //Extra formatting or whatever you need to do can go here
    }
    //Other code goes here
    $first=false;
}
```

Comment: Wow. That is such an awesome solution!
So simple I didn't think of it!
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'm definitly going with this solution, its just perfect!
I'm also stunned by the speed you all answerred my question, thank you all so much!

Comment: @laarsk, No problem.  If this worked for you, you should accept it as the answer by clicking the check mark to the left.  You can read more about this here:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Yeah,, though after the explanation from Jeremy, I realised that might even be a better solution: even more simple!

Comment: @laarsk, that is fine.  Although, I wouldn't do it that way, for the reasons Jonathan Kuhn mentioned.

Comment: I didnt really understand that reason, about the duplicating the code, but I guess if you all say so, I'm about to go with youre code.
though you forgot one thing: there needs to be an else statement after the closing bracket of the if loop

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  What is wrong with it?  If you downvote something, you should really explain why, for the benefit of everyone.

Comment: @laarsk, I didn't say that you did.  I was asking the person who did, why they did, so we can all learn something from it.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run `mysql_fetch_array` it fetches the *next* row anyway, so you could just run it once outside your loop, and then have the loop go through the remaining rows.

What's *not* happening is a `mysql_data_seek`, which *would* cause it to restart at the top, but you're not doing that!

Example

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
# process first row here

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    # process second and subsequent rows here
}
```

Comment: But how would I have it grab only one row? Thanks for the post, but I don't fully understand what you are saying..

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` fetches one row (or returns false) every time you run it. If you run it outside a loop, it just fetches the next row from the set. The first time, that means it fetches the _first_ row. So if you run it outside the loop at the beginning, it's fetching the first row.

Comment: ooh ok, So that would even be an easier solution than the one Brad provided?

Comment: Sure. No extra variable required.

Comment: @Shrapnel: would you care to explain yourself?

Comment: depending on the end result of what you are trying, you would be duplicating code in both the `#process first...` and `process second...` sections. Also if the query returns 0 rows (which is always possible) the first $row will be false so you need to check for that where the `while` will skip over the loop when 0 rows with no extra checking. Just a few ideas off the top of my head.

Comment: @laarsk, Jeremy's answer isn't wrong.  Usually your first row is going to have one thing slightly different (like a CSS class or something), so the part that echos the row would be (nearly) duplicated for the first row, and within the loop.  But his answer certainly isn't wrong, and is appropriate in some cases.  You should pick the solution based on your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

```
for ($i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); $i++) {
  $row[$i]
}
```

of course it is literal, but totally useless answer.
To show data on your website, you should use a template.
So, you have to get your data into array first anyway

Comment: fixed it. $row[$i] should probably also be just $row with $i as the count of the current row.